# CSS3 + jQuery page flip timing tweak

Tags: jquery, css

Well, im trying to build a fullscreen page flip with css3 transitions and jQuery to add/remove certain effects. So far I've managed to build up the effects and proper class change. But i can't place one page "behind" another while the transition is happening.

I've tried working with z-index for the page2 (which is the page behind the first one), But i can't make this work.

http://www2.madeinweb.com.br/jobs/page-flip/

This is the proto im working on right now.

```
$('.page1').removeClass('flip in reverse').addClass('flip out').delay(650).hide(0);
$('.page2').removeClass('flip out reverse').addClass('flip in').delay(650).show(0);
```

The jQuery class triggering.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you removing the `flip` class and then adding it right back?

Comment: @Blazemonger its working like a "hard" reset. I was facing some problems spamming the next/back button. remove the class before adding it again fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've managed to make this work with absolute positioning. Didnt want to use this workaround but thats the cleanest way I've found.